# How to remove checkboxes from parent rows in Lightning:treeGrid in Aura component and keep them on children rows only

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningtreegrid

How can I remove the checkboxes on the first column of the TreeGrid for the parent rows and only keep the checkboxes for the children rows?
I've read countless articles and the only thing I found so far is setting the `hide-checkbox-column` attribute to true in the `lightning-tree-grid` component, but this removes all the checkboxes.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: i dont  think  it would be possible.  you can also  take a look at official  doc.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation.   you can develop  a custom solution using slds  styling  and your logic.

Comment: @gauravsharma Thank you for the link!! Can you please give me some pointers about implementing my own custom solution? I'm new to salesforce so I have no idea how to do that

Comment: @Dr.Simplisisti have  updated the answer  from high level perspective.  please also  take a look of a basic  lwc  implementation.  https://webcomponents.dev/edit/k97nyPYUViWp2LBAIWXb/src/app.html?p=stories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have  a custom logic   for  checkbox, to best of my knowledge  you need to develop  custom treegrid.

from high level perspective  to develop  acustom treegrid  ,   you need to develop  nested  table  structure.

please refer to treegrid  blueprint:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/#site-main-content

Create  a nested  table  using  slds design.

use nested template for:each  in lwc each for parent  and child   or aura:iteration   in aura   to show   nested table data.

modify  your nested  json data  containing  parent and child in init  of aura  or  connectecallback of lwc  and add some  custom property  for   your checkbox logic   and  to hide/show   child data.

please also  refer to a very basic  custom implementation in lwc.
https://webcomponents.dev/edit/k97nyPYUViWp2LBAIWXb/src/app.html?p=stories

Comment: Thank you so very much! I really apreciate it! I'll try what you recommended and let you know of the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to get this done:

```
.THIS tr[aria-level="1"]  > td[data-col-key-value="0-SELECTABLE_CHECKBOX-0"]{
    visibility:hidden !important;
 }
```

Might not be the best way to do it, but it worked for me...
Cheers!

Comment: its not working when i tried.please put with example.